# how to read data in uart and execute a loop at the same time?

Tags: c, uart

my program is racing game. The problem is I want the enemy cars to move even when I don't press any key for UART to receive.

When it reaches the key reading instruction(Serial.read), it does not execute any other instruction like, the enemy speed function, which allows moving the enemy tanks.

how can I execute that function even if I don't write any letter in the uart?

```
#include "tm4c123gh6pm.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "tivaduino.h"
#include "Nokia5110.h"

//library

uint8_t HardwareSerial0::read(void){
    uint8_t datoRx;
    
    while(UART0_FR_R & 0x10==0x10); 
    

//UART0_FR_R is in 1 if transmission buffer is full (no data is sent). if not, data can be sent to the buffer and it sends to TIVA

    datoRx = (uint8_t)UART0_DR_R;
    return datoRx;

}
```

//one option that i was thinking was using UART_FR_TXFE in "read"

```
//main program
 while (1) {


//is responsible for moving enemy cars to the far left and then disappear

Nokia5110_enemy_speed (positionk1, positionk2, positionk3, positionk4, positionk5,
             positionh1, positionh2, positionh3, positionh4, positionh5); 


//read a key on the uart (defined to be w, a, s, d)
char_key = Serial.read ();

sprintf (key, "% c", char_key); `//convert char_key into string`


if ((h <24) && (h> = 0)) {// as long as x remains on the map

   if ((strcmp (key, "w") == 0) && (h> 0)) {

Nokia5110_clean_cart (k, h);
h = h-8;
        Nokia5110_drawing_cart (k, h);
    }
     if ((strcmp (key, "s") == 0) && (h <16)) {
Nokia5110_clean_cart (k, h);
       h = h + 8;
   
      Nokia5110_drawing_cart (k, h);
    }
if ((strcmp (key, "d") == 0) && (k <78)) {
    Nokia5110_clean_cart (k, h);
       k = k + 6;
   
      Nokia5110_drawing_cart (k, h);
    }
if ((strcmp (key, "a") == 0) && (k> 0)) {
     Nokia5110_clean_cart (k, h);
       k = k-6;
    
     Nokia5110_drawing_cart (k, h);
    }

  }

 
}
```

Comment: use interrupts do not poll

Answer (score 0):

You are actively waiting for next byte from UART. Instead, try just checking if there is received byte. If so, return it, otherwise return some "empty" code. For example:

```
return (UART0_FR_R & 0x10 == 0x00) ? (uint8_t)UART0_DR_R : 0xff;
```

I chose `0xff` as a mark for "no char read" (assuming that no vlid key has code 0xff).

Comment: bad idea use UART interrupts instead of polling

Comment: @P__J__ Whether something is a good or bad idea depends on use case. I agree, but sometimes you may need precise timing not disturbed by interrupts or so.

Comment: for precise timings timers are used not the very imprecise polling.

Comment: @P__J__ I agree that interrupts are usually handier than polling. What I am saying is that polling is not *generally* bad idea and has it's use-cases.

Comment: in your solution it should return `int` and -1 will distinct from all possible received values

Comment: ' What I am saying is that polling is not generally bad idea', oh yes, it is.

Comment: @MartinJames Because...?